# Have changeable button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, timer, stopwatch

I'm currently learning Swift and iOS programming. I have learned to create a stopwatch app that displays a stopwatch. I'm trying currently to have the start and stop button for the stopwatch combined. This means that when the app is loaded, it'll have a start button but when I press the start button, it turns into a stop button and when I press that the timer stops and the button changes to a start button. I've searched the internet and stack overflow but I'm unable to find something similar to what I want. My current code is attached below!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var timer = NSTimer()

var count = 0.0

func updateTime() {

    count = count + 0.1

    label.text = "\(count)"

}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: ("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }

@IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

}


@IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

    count = 0

    label.text = "0"

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: You are using any image or just text on a button?

Comment: Wow! That was quick. I'm using something called a bar button item

Comment: Are you using the bar button item inside a navigationBar or toolbar? This is actually important, because the answer is slightly more involved than using standard buttons (but still nothing complicated).

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the IBActions and just do this , just deleting the actions is not enough , you need to right click your buttons and disconnect all   @IBactions to remove the complete references else youll get error  ..

> // dont make this @IBAction this is just a normal function

```
 func start() {
>     timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: ("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
> 
> 
>     } // smae here... just a function   
     func updateTime() {
> 
>     count = count + 0.1
> 
>     label.text = "\(count)"
> 
> } // same with this just a function 
>        func reset() {
> 
>     timer.invalidate()
> 
>     count = 0
> 
>     label.text = "0"
> 
> }  
> 
> // Now Make a @IBAction to your button , and sender should be UIButton
> 
>

     @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender : UIButton) {   
     if sender.currentTitle == "start" {
    >       sender.setTitle("stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    >       reset() // perform any function that you want to when button is acting as stop button    } 
    else {
    >        sender.setTitle("start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    >        start() // perform any function that you want to when button is acting as start button 
    >      } }
```

Comment: I think @justinxfan also wanted to switch the image on press. So you'll need to make another link to the button on the storyboard, this time an `IBOutlet` say named `myButton` and add something like `self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "StartButton.png") as UIImage!, forState: .Normal)` when you want to switch the image.

Comment: you dont need to make @IBOutlet , you can do that without that 
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "StartButton.png") , forState: .Normal)

Comment: but this code should be inside the @IBaction buttonpressed(sender : UIButton)

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice you had the sender as a UIButton!